# Send admin an email when a user's search has no results

Tags: plugins, search, email

I'm new to WordPress. What is the easiest way to trigger an email to admin when a user's search has no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided much info so I will give you a basic example.

You need to find whatever template your theme is using to display the results, possibly search.php.  If this isn't your theme create a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) and duplicate the file that displays the results.

This file should already have an `if` statement for displaying the results, possibly an `if/else`.  If not you will need to add one.  The Else is used for when there are no results.  You can grab what was entered in the search with [get_search_query()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_query/).

Inside the else you can use [wp_mail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) to send an email.

For Example:

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    // Code to display your results
else:
    // No results so send an email
    $query = get_search_query();
    $to = 'adminEmail@mail.com';
    $subject = 'User Search';
    $message = 'User searched  ' . $query;
    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message );
endif;
```